# How to consume a WCF soap web service in an angular client

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, wcf, soap

I'm working on a legacy code already developed with **WCF, .NET and silverlight** in the client.
I want to develop a new client application using **angular** 6/7 using the same web service (WCF, soap & XML communication).
Is there any way to make calls to a soap service from an **angular client**

I have tried to follow some tutorials including this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap
It didn't work for me yet.
Is it the right choice ?
If so, how can I use this library?
If not what are the other alternatives?

Comment: Why not to use the standard http client? The only problem you may encounter is parsing the XML response.

Comment: @kaosdev -  generating the outgoing mesages with the proper SOAP schemas would be a bigger challenge. Essentially a SOAP framework, what the OP is asking for.